# Flutter: How to reference files into main.dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is a screenshot of my main.dart file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WGQj.png

And a screenshot of my home_page.dart file which I want to reference INTO main.dart: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8TeS.png

How do I reference the home_page.dart file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class name *_LoginPage* has underscore in front of the name, which means it's private and can't be imported in any other file. To make it visible, remove underscore from the name (i.e., *LoginPage*). And you have to import *main.dart* inside of *home_page.dart* file to import *MyApp* class.

Comment: @NadiaM Please, accept/upvote the answers that solved your problems. No need to thank in comments.